# Pass generic type class method as parameter

Tags: java, android, list, generics, reflection

Is there any way to pass a method of a generic type as a parameter?
What I try to achieve is something like this:

```
ListUtils.mapObjectToField( entries, Contact.getZipCode );
```

I pass a `List<T>` and a method from the generic class `T`.
So far I am fine with the generic List but I am not able to achieve the method call.

```
public static <T, U> List<U> mapObjectToField( List<T>elements, /*generic method*/ )
{
    List<U> result = new ArrayList<>();

    for ( T current : elements )
    {
        result.add(current./*generic method*/);
    }
    return result;
}
```

No Java 8 as I am coding for Android min SDK 14.

Comment: If you passed the name of the method as a string you could do it with reflection but it wouldn't be pretty.

Comment: When you implement the actual code to be executed somewhere else, why do you need this method at all?

Comment: I'd suggest you to take a look in java.util.function.Function<T, R> It does pretty much what you want.

Comment: https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#transform-java.util.List-com.google.common.base.Function- -- exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best way would be to implement it like `Stream.map` in Java 8 and provide your own interface, perhaps called `Mapper`, but to provide an implementation at the call site, you'll have to use an anonymous inner class. Lambdas are much nicer.

It might look like this:

```
public interface Mapper<T, U> {
    U map(T t);
}
```

ListUtils would like this:

```
public class ListUtils {
    public static List<U> mapObjectToField(List<T> elements, Mapper<T, U> mapper) {
        List<U> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (T current : elements) {
            result.add(mapper.map(current));
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

And you could call it like this:

```
List<String> zipCodes = ListUtils.mapObjectToField(contacts,
    new Mapper<Contact, String>() {
        public String map(Contact contact) {
            return contact.getZipCode();
        }
    });
```

You can define the mapper elsewhere, which will clean up the appearance somewhat, but it won't be as nice as having lambdas.

Comment: Although it does not really answer the question to pass a method it is exactly what i was trying to achieve so thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use reflection just do like this (But it is not recommended solution),

```
public static <T, U> List<U> mapObjectToField( List<T>elements, String methodName )
    {
        List<U> result = new ArrayList<>();
        Method method = null;

        for ( T current : elements )
        {
            if(method == null){
                try {
                    method = current.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(methodName);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
            }

            U object = (U) invokeMethod(current, method);
            result.add(object);
        }
        return result;
    }


public static Object invokeMethod(Object obj , Method method)
    {
        if (method != null) {
            try {
                Object value = method.invoke(obj);
                return value;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Retrolambda** to have lambdas and method references also in android SDK 14.

https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda

The code suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/42996933/802034 will become:

```
  public void main(){
    List<Integer> lengths = mapObjectToField(nCopies(5, "hello"), String::length);
  }

  public static <T, U> List<U> mapObjectToField(List<T> elements, Mapper<T, U> mapper) {
    List<U> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (T current : elements) {
      result.add(mapper.map(current));
    }
    return result;
  }

  public interface Mapper<T, U> {
    U map(T t);
  }


}
```

If you want go further and use **Streams**, you can on android with this library: https://github.com/aNNiMON/Lightweight-Stream-API

```
 List<Integer> lengths =
        Stream.of(nCopies(5, "hello"))
              .map(String::length)
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```